# Wireshark unable to assemble TCP packets into RTMP packets

Tags: wireshark, rtmp

Basically, I have the same problem as this guy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033200/wireshark-cant-resolve-rtmp-handshake-packets-and-some-rtmp-packets-unknown, except that my Wireshark doesn't recognize anything at all (everything is either TCP or Unknown(0x0) RTMP).

I didn't have this problem before when I was running Wireshark 1.6.5 with winPcap 4.1.2, but after I updated to winPcap 4.1.3 (because another program complained about winPcap missing "packet.dll") I got this problem. I uninstalled everything and installed Wireshark 1.12.1 with winPcap 4.1.3 but the problem persists.

I've always had the options "Reassemble RTMPT messages spanning multiple TCP segments" and "Try heuristic sub-dissectors first" enabled.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Generally Unknown(0x0) RTMP indicates that may be handshake between client and server did not perform well. Due to this further communication could not be carried out.Try capturing the data again and check.